# If I have a url is there a way to figure out how many reddit votes it has?

Tags: javascript, json, reddit

When I say url it doesn't necessarily have to be a url on the reddit.com domain but simply just one submitted to the site.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

http://code.reddit.com/wiki/API

Official Reddit API :)